# PyTorch cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll existed but could not be found when using spacy to download

Tags: pytorch, spacy, cudnn, oserror

When I used spacy (a library) to download, it showed that

`OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\haoli\anaconda3\envs\ifcmapping\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll" or one of its dependencies.`

But `cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll` actually existed, as the picture below shows. Then what is the problem? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is because I used `conda` to install PyTorch and used `pip` to install the spacy library. When I used `conda` to install both of them it worked.